# Setup Wordpress with Magento using Ngix shows 404 Error

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, nginx, fishpig

I am using magento2 and fishpig WordPress integration extension and using Nginx Server. Wordpress directory is on magento root with name "wp".

Magento is working fine and display the blog content but when accessing the WordPress admin URL or frontend it shows 404 error page not found.

After research, I found that we have to do the setting in Nginx config file (/etc/Nginx/sites-available) and setup the location of wp directory.

Below are the code which i have tried to add in Nginx Config file

```
location  /wp {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/index.php?$args;
}   

location  /wp {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
} 

location  /wp/wp-admin/ {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/wp-admin/index.php?$args;
}
```

Below are some URL which I have gone through -:

[Nginx configuration for a wordpress blog in a subfolder of magento root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646457/nginx-configuration-for-a-wordpress-blog-in-a-subfolder-of-magento-root)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento-wordpress-integration-nginx

Below is my Nginx file.

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name magento.online.com;
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/prod;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

        root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

        index index.php;
        autoindex off;
        charset UTF-8;
    #@raj
        error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
        #add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

        # PHP entry point for setup application
        location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
            root $MAGE_ROOT;
            location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
                fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
            }

            location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
                deny all;
            }

            location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            }
        }

        # PHP entry point for update application
        location ~* ^/update($|/) {
            root $MAGE_ROOT;

            location ~ ^/update/index.php {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
                include        fastcgi_params;
            }

            # Deny everything but index.php
            location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
                deny all;
            }

            location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            }
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

  #wordpress Code 
    #   location /wordpress/ {
    #       try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
    #   }


        location  /wp/wp-admin/ {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/wp-admin/index.php?$args;
       }



    #   location /wp/wp-admin/ {
    #       index index.php index.html index.htm;
     #          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    #   }

#End of code

        location /pub/ {
            location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
                deny all;
            }
            alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }

        location /static/ {
            # Uncomment the following line in production mode
            # expires max;

            # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
            location ~ ^/static/version {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
            }

            location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires +1y;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
                }
            }
            location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires    off;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
                }
            }
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }

        location /media/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

            location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
                deny all;
            }

            location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires +1y;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
            }
            location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires    off;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
            }
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }

        location /media/customer/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location /media/downloadable/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location /media/import/ {
            deny all;
        }

        # PHP entry point for main application
        location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

            fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
            fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=600";
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types
            text/plain
            text/css
            text/js
            text/xml
            text/javascript
            application/javascript
            application/x-javascript
            application/json
            application/xml
            application/xml+rss
            image/svg+xml;
        gzip_vary on;

        # Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
        location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
            deny all;
        }   


    }


    #
    ## Optional override of deployment mode. We recommend you use the
    ## command 'bin/magento deploy:mode:set' to switch modes instead.
    ##
    ## set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
    ##
    ## If you set MAGE_MODE in server config, you must pass the variable into the
    ## PHP entry point blocks, which are indicated below. You can pass
    ## it in using:
    ##
    ## fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
    ##
    ## In production mode, you should uncomment the 'expires' directive in the /static/ location block
```

Any help will be really appriciated.

Comment: Hello, I know it's an old thread but did you find a fix ? I'm having the same issue thanks !

Answer (score 0):

When integrating WordPress into Magento, you don't need to do anything special with the rewrites that you wouldn't do as normal to get WordPress working on Nginx.

You might not even need the rewrites at all. The rewrites exist to route all frontend requests through index.php to provide pretty SEO URLs. This functionality of WordPress isn't being used as the frontend is being displayed by Magento, therefore the rewrites may not be needed. All requests to the WordPress Admin are to files that exist and therefore rewrites shouldn't be needed.